# Function typing a substring of string variable into a textbox character by character

Tags: javascript

So, it is working when I pass no argument and within the function I give it one, specific variable to type. Anyway, I want the function to be flexible and work with any variable I call it with.

```
var msg = "some text";

function writer(x) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
    text.textContent = x.substring(0, i);
    i++;
        if (i <= 60) {
            writer();
            } 
    }, 20)

};  

writer(msg);
```

Not working either.

```
i=0;

var msg = "some text";

function writer() {
    setTimeout(function (x) { 
    text.textContent = x.substring(0, i);
    i++;
        if (i <= 60) {
            writer();
            } 
    }, 20)

};  

writer(msg);
```

GOT IT!

```
i=0;

var msg = "some text";

function writer(x) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
    text.textContent = x.substring(0, i);
    i++;
        if (i <= 60) {
            writer(x);
            } 
    }, 20)

};  

writer(msg);
```

Comment: what is the output of your code?

Comment: well you do not pass anything to writer in the recursion call...

Comment: Also, where do you first set `i`?

Comment: i is set way before function

Comment: Two problems, the "i" variable is not initialized to 0 and the recursive call to writer() is empty.

Comment: i variable is initialized to 0, i passed x into the recursive call. not working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8wye1n7s/
I took a fresh crack at it. Might be worth a look for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is you are not passing the text to the method. You would need to pass the message inside the timeout. Other solution is to not pass in the message and just use the global variable.

```js
var msg = "some text",
    i = 0,
    text = document.getElementById("out1");

function writer (x) {  
    setTimeout(function () { 
        text.textContent = x.substring(0, i);  //or change x to msg and do not worry about passing in the string
        i++;
        if (i <= x.length) {  //base off length, not a random number
            writer(x);  //or get rid of x
        } 
    }, 20);
};  

writer(msg);
```

```html
<div id="out1"></div>
```

The other issue with your code is you are relying on global variables (they might be in a different scope than local) so you would not be able to run the code multiple times without collisions. So a better idea is to enclose the recursion inside of your method and call that so you can maintain the state of each instance.

Basic idea:

```js
function writer(element, message, speed) {
  
    var currentStep = 0;  //holds where we are in the text animation
    speed = speed || 200; //If no value given, set to a default
    function step() {  // a local function that will hold the state of the variables so we do not have to pass anything around
        element.textContent = message.substr(0, currentStep++);  //set the text and update the step we are on    
        if (currentStep<=message.length) {  //Check to see if we still have more characters to dislay
            setTimeout(step, speed);  //if we do, set the timeout
        }
    }
  
    step();  //init the animation

};  

//Examples calling it
writer(document.getElementById("out1"), "Hello World! How are you doing today?" );
writer(document.getElementById("out2"), "Hello World! How are you?", 400 );
```

```html
<div id="out1"></div>
<div id="out2"></div>
```